# How to integrate Alfresco with my website such that both share same login page?

Tags: php, mysql, alfresco, alfresco-share

Currently i am working on an ERP system such that it contain 2 module. First module is on php and mysql and second module is [Alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/). I just want to have a common login page for both module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is called Single Sign-On. To implement this, you'll start with an LDAP directory of some sort (OpenLDAP, for example) and use that to manage your users and their login credentials. Then, you'll implement a Single Sign-On provider to handle authentication. A common one is called [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas). Finally, you'll configure your PHP app and Alfresco to use the login page provided by CAS. CAS will be responsible for authenticating users and providing/validating authentication tokens for the apps participating in Single Sign-On.

Comment: And if you do not want to implement LDAP authentication, Then another way is like you can create custom web scripts in alfresco and make user registration page in PHP, same you can authenticate the user also.

Also, you can bootstrap your alfresco application that will create a patch, at the initial time it'll create users with default username and password, you can force users to change the password for it.

At last you can also manage login at both level PHP and Alfresco for better security.

All the best...